# .p12 certificate file for ios developing

Tags: ios, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I have .p12 "apple development iOS push service" certificate file for iOS developing(Push notification),then I don't have apple id and password through which this certificate is created as it is unsafe to give apple id to someone so here is the question: can i use this certificate to develop app for push notification with GCM? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The push service certificates are used on a server to send remote notifications via the push service.  You'll need a separate certificate through an Apple Developer account to develop the app itself.

Comment: Yeah after that i need apple developer license id for xcode or these 2 licenses will suffice??as i dont have that

Comment: Xcode is free through the apple store. You can download it.  It looks like you are just starting out (since you don't have Xcode yet).  You might want to do some research on how to develop iOS apps, as it is very complicated.

Comment: Sorry i was not clear enough i do have xcode but dont have developer license and instead i have free provisioning cert which let me debug on apple device.My company have (apple devloper license and id  and doesn't want to give it to me as I am an intern and clearly i dont have any iOS developing history).So my question remains do apple require all developers to have developer certificate to test push notification or they allow some kind of company project where senior developer make certificate and junior can use it to develop company project.Thanks for listening.

Comment: Apple has the concept of a team, where there is one master developer - the agent, who can use his certificate to sign an app for the app store, and team members.  You can sign up and get an Apple Developer account for free (you may already have one).  Get your company to invite you as a member of their team, and you can download mobile provisioning and use them for development.